# display image from byte array by api controller in angular js

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, api, cordova

I have an application whose server side is asp.net. I want to display the images stored as an array of bytes on the ِDatabase by api controller in the app. It is an angular js app.
On the server side, the image is stored in the database as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(House house,HttpPostedFileBase Photon)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        house.Id = Guid.NewGuid();

        if (Photon != null && Photon.ContentType.StartsWith("image"))
        {
            mImage img = new mImage
            {
                Photo = new byte[Photon.ContentLength],
                PhotoType = Photon.ContentType,
                photoName = Photon.FileName,
                HouseId = house.Id
            };
            Photon.InputStream.Read(img.Photo, 0, Photon.ContentLength);
            db.mImages.Add(img);
        }
        var area = db.Areas.Find(house.AreaId);
        house.visit = 0;
        db.Houses.Add(house);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    ViewBag.AreaId = new SelectList(db.Areas, "Id", "name", house.AreaId);
    return View(house);
}
```

And is displayed in this way.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult ShowPhoto(Guid id)
{
    using (var db = new myDB())
    {
        var p = db.mImages.Find(id);
        System.IO.MemoryStream myMemStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(p.Photo);
        System.Drawing.Image fullsizeImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(myMemStream);
        System.Drawing.Image newImage = fullsizeImage.GetThumbnailImage(150, 150, null, IntPtr.Zero);
        System.IO.MemoryStream myResult = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        newImage.Save(myResult, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);  //Or whatever format you want.

        return File(myResult.ToArray(), "image/Jpeg");
    }
}
```

How to use this method to display images in api controller?

Comment: Am I missing something or could you not just reference is as a URL in an `img` tag like so; `<img src="\Controller\ShowPhoto\00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" />` (replace with actual guid)?

Comment: i do this work in my asp.net mvc controller but i want show images in cordova app by api controller,how can i use the images that saved in the data base,they saved like byte array

Comment: that being the case if you're using WebApi to return the byte array then have your method's return type to be `byte[]`. If you're serving this from a normal controller then you'll need to serialize the byte array (usually as JSON) and return that as a `JsonResult`. Or have I misunderstood the requirement?

Comment: thank u so much my friend i solved it by json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the solution here as per the comments on the OP. The solution was to serialize the byte array as json and return it as a `JsonResult` to the effect of the following;

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult ShowPhoto(Guid id)
{
    using (var db = new myDB())
    {
        var p = db.mImages.Find(id);
        System.IO.MemoryStream myMemStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(p.Photo);
        System.Drawing.Image fullsizeImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(myMemStream);
        System.Drawing.Image newImage = fullsizeImage.GetThumbnailImage(150, 150, null, IntPtr.Zero);
        System.IO.MemoryStream myResult = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        newImage.Save(myResult, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);      //Or whatever format you want.

        return Json(new { myResult.ToArray() });
    }
}
```